# Update DATE in MS Access using Vb.NET update command

Tags: vb.net, date

Hi I want to update DATE in MS Access using Vb.NET update command. I used Date picker tool and datatype for date is date/time. I used debugging and everything is coming perfect in variables but when i check the updation date and month remains correct which i selected but year changed to 1894 ....
CODE IS :

```
Dim dt As String
dt = Format(Dtp1.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy")
Cmd.Parameters.Clear()
Cmd.CommandText = "update tran set expdate=" & dt & " where trno=" & TxtMTrNo.Text.Trim
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
LoadProducts()

TxtMTrNo.Text = ""
TxtMProduct.Text = ""
TxtPQty.Text = ""
TxtSQty.Text = ""

MsgBox("Edited successfull")
```

Comment: if the` expdate` is a date column in the database, you should pass a date value, not a string.  Also, validate user input - what if `TxtMTrNo` is something like "I like pie"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the date in single quotes:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "update tran set expdate='" & dt & "' where trno=" & TxtMTrNo.Text.Trim
```

Otherwise it thinks the date is a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string concatenation... this is bug-prone(date format locality issue) and vulnerable to SQL injection issues. Use parameters instead, something like this:

```
Cmd.CommandText = "update tran set expdate=@pDate where .....
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDate ", ......
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I used single quotes with data parameter and its working...